# Declaring properties properly

Tags: c#, activereports

For some reason since the last Visual Studio 2015 update, my code crashes with a StackOverflow when running my reports from Grape City ActiveReports.  It seems to crash when I am setting properties on the report.  The question is which is the best way to define properties?

I want to send a some value to my class objects like:

```
MyClass clsObj = new MyClass();
clsObj.MyProperty = 1;
```

This is what I do now as a sample:

```
public class MyClass() {
   public int MyProperty;
}
```

But if you use the shortcut for prop and press tab you get this:

```
public class MyClass() {
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I then see where people do this:

```
public class MyClass() {
        private int _MyProperty;
        public int MyProperty { get { return _MyProperty; } set {_MyProperty = value; } }
}
```

Which is the best practice?

Comment: Your first example is a field, not a property. Your second example has an automatically implemented backing field, and is roughly equivalent to the third example, though much shorter (and thus is favorable).

Comment: What you "do now" is not a property, but a **field**.

Comment: What do you mean by a field and not a property?

Comment: [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

Comment: As for why you get a crash, you'll have to provide more info about what you're doing. Highly unlikely you're getting a stack overflow when setting a property or field, unless you're doing some recursive setting, which I would find unlikely.

Comment: Short answer for fields vs properties: fields are variables. Properties are  closer to methods, which *can* act like fields. The simplest difference is that properties can have logic within them, while fields cannot.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Actually a recursive set is a common bug in properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you want to use your properties.

The usual way properties are written is like so:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

The code above is the same as writing this:

```
public int MyProperty { get { return _MyProperty; } set {_MyProperty = value; } }
```

you don't need the extra backing field unless you want to perform some other logic within the properties getter and setter.

in C# 6.0 you can now do property initializers like this:

```
public DateTime TimeStamp { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

You can use that instead of initializing the property in a constructor of a class.

As for your code not working, I can't really tell, you haven't posted enough information.

Microsoft have a lot of information on c# 6.0 properties here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx